# how to insert multiple line textarea value in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a textarea and I want to insert values of that textarea to a mysql table. But I want to insert each line to each field. Like the textarea has 3 lines...each line should be inserted in 3 each field in the table. Can anyone please help me with this.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Explode the value of the textarea (see PHP manual for the syntax of explode). You will end up with a string array with 3 items. Now you can process each of these items individually.

Do you really mean columns (fields) and not rows? If someone enters 100 lines in the textarea you would neet 100 columns. This is considered to be bad data design.

Comment: am afraid to say that this is the design